# Что такое __peg_parser__?

Tags: python, python-3.9, keyword

У меня установлен Python 3.9. При исследовании встроенных модулей Python с помощью интерпретатора я обнаружил следующее непонятное явление:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['False', 'None', 'True', '__peg_parser__', 'and', ... , 'yield']
```

Стало интересно, что это за peg_parser.

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1
      help(__peg_parser__)
           ^
    SyntaxError: You found it!
```

Может, это пасхалка какая-нибудь? Или от этого пегпарсера есть и практическая польза?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/

Comment: @andreymal, это совсем не то, просто названия похожие. Про __peg_parser__ в этой статье ничего нет.

Comment: Ну тогда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486981

Comment: А, тогда понятно. Это действительно, похоже, просто-напросто пасхалка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**peg_parser** – это пасхалка (Easter egg) в языке Python.

Если попробовать вызвать `help(__peg_parser__)` или обратиться к этому атрибуту напрямую, Python вызовет исключение SyntaxError с сообщением "You found it!" («Вы нашли это!»). Это было спрятано разработчиками языка Python как шуточный отклик на попытки исследовать `__peg_parser__`.